# MODE_MULTI_PROCESS for SharedPreferences isn't working

Tags: android, multiprocessing, sharedpreferences

I have a `SyncAdapter` running on its own process separately from the main app process.

I'm using a static wrapper class around my `SharedPreferences` that creates a static object on process load (Application's `onCreate`) like so:

```
myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS | Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

The wrapper has get and set methods, like so:

```
public static String getSomeString() {
    return myPrefs.getString(SOME_KEY, null);
}

public static void setSomeString(String str) {
    myPrefs.edit().putString(SOME_KEY, str).commit();
}
```

Both `SyncAdapter` and app uses this wrapper class to edit and get from the prefs, this works sometimes but a lot of times I see the `SyncAdapter` getting old/missing prefs on accesses to the prefs, while the main app sees the recent changes properly.

According to the docs I think the `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` flag should work as I expect it to, allowing both processes to see latest changes, but it doesn't work.

**Update:**

Per `x90`'s suggestion, I've tried refraining from using a static `SharedPreferences` object and instead calling `getSharedPreferences` on each get/set method.
This caused a new issue, where the prefs file gets deleted (!!!) on multi-process simultaneous access. 
i.e. I see in the logcat:

```
(process 1): getName => "Name"
(process 2): getName => null
(process 1): getName => null
```

and from that point all the prefs saved on the `SharedPreferences` object were deleted.

This is probably a result of another warning I see in the log:

```
W/FileUtils(21552): Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.my_company/shared_prefs/prefs_filename.xml): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

P.S this is not a deterministic issue, I saw the above logs after a crash happened, but couldn't recreate yet on the same device, and until now it didn't seem to happen on other devices.

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

I've filed a bug report on this, after writing a small testing method to confirm this is indeed an Android issue, star it at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66625

Comment: Have you tried to get preference object on demand (every time you want to work with preferences) and not hold a reference on SharedPreferences object all time in Application class?

Comment: I thought about it, but this will be a very major change to the entire app, and is not currently an option due to the size of the code. I haven't seen any mention in the docs of having a static prefs object might prevent MULTI_PROCESS from working properly... any reason you might think this is the culprit?

Comment: I'm expecting (not sure) that root cause can be java threading layer. This object can be cached in threads (processes) in different state and give different results. Anyway i think you can try to change your work flow with sharedpreferences (in the way i described before).

Comment: If it is a solution - you can create api for working with shared preferences which require context. It can be not so usable (if you want to work with prefs from object that dont have a context) but i suggest you to look in this way.

Comment: And something about multi-proces android nature. As i know Dalvik have separate classloader for every process. So if you hold your preference object even as static - this object can be loaded twice and cached for every process.

Comment: Ok, I was able to have the prefs file re-created for every set/get call, I'll give it a few days and report back my findings, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Nope... still not working perfectly, see above update.

Comment: @marmor we have the "preferences file gets deleted" problem plaguing us in production. I've starred the Android issue, but any fix there will never reach most existing devices. I was wondering if you've found a workaround between March and now?

Comment: @Barend I saw you comment on the Android issue, has this issues started happening after adding the new process? If the other process isn't reading or writing to prefs it sounds like a different issue. If most of the reports come from old Samsung devices it may be https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14359

Comment: It definitely first started happening in the release where we added the `android:process` element. I'm less certain about not using the shared prefs; the subprocess is running a third party native lib.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this with? We had major issues with multi-process access to SharedPreferences and eventually dumped it all and replaced it with our own implementation that uses an SQLite database as backing store.

Comment: [MODE_MULTI_PROCESS **This constant was deprecated in API level 23.**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Had exactly the same problem and my solution was to write a ContentProvider based replacement for the SharedPreferences. It works 100% multiprocess.

I made it a library for all of us. Here is the result:
https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray

Comment: It is going to be a good option as it was deprecated in Android 6: [MODE_MULTI_PROCESS **This constant was deprecated in API level 23.**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)

Comment: Working like charm.You save my day :)

Answer (score 27):

I gave a very quick look at Google's code and apparently `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` is not an actual way to ensure process-safety of SharedPreferences.

SharedPreferences itself is not process-safe. (That's probably why SharedPreferences documentation says "currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later.")

`MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` just works in conjunction with every `Context.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` call: when you retrieve an instance of SharedPreferences specifying the `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` flag android will reload the preferences file to be up to date with any (eventual) concurrent modification that occurred to it. If you then keep that instance as a class (static or not) member, the preference file won't be reloaded again.

Using `Context.getSharedPreferences(...)` every time you want to write or read into preferences is not process-safe either, but I guess it's probably the closest that you can get to it at the moment.

If you don't actually need to read the same preference from the different processes, then a workaround could be to use different preferences files for the different processes.

Comment: yep, seems like there's currently no good multi-process way of saving and reading preferences.

Comment: [MODE_MULTI_PROCESS **This constant was deprecated in API level 23.**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)

Comment: `objPreferences.contains(key);` this return false in service even data is stored in preference. How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into the same problem. I switched my app to run the service in a separate process and realized sharedPreferences was all broken.

Two things:

1) Are you using `Editor.apply()` or `.commit()`? I was using `.apply()`. I started checking my preference file either after the activity or the service made changes to it and realized whenever one would make a change, it would create a new file with only the newly changed value. I.E., a value written from the activity would be erased when a new value was written/changed from the service and vice versa. **I switched to `.commit()` everywhere and this is no longer the case!** From the documentation: *"Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time, the last one to call apply wins.*

2) `SharedPreferencesListener` doesn't appear to work across processes even after switching to `.commit()`. You'll have to use Messenger Handlers or Broadcast Intents to notify of a change. When you look at the documentation for the SharedPreferences class it even says *"Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later."* http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

In that respect we're lucky we even have the `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` flag working to read/write from the same `SharedPreferences` across different processes.

Comment: No, I've used only "commit", and as I said this might work ok, but once in few days of regular usage of my 2-processes app and the prefs would get reset.
So I wrote the above loop to check it, and it shows the problem appears within a minute or two of extensive writing and reading.
Can you try running a loop of reads and writes of a random number from your service and your main app, and see if you can recreate my findings?

Comment: `objPreferences.contains(key);` this return false in service even data is stored in preference. How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

MODE_MULTI_PROCESS for SharedPreferences is depreciated now (android M -API level 23-onward).It was not process safe.

Answer (score 2):

MODE_MULTI_PROCESS was deprecated in API level 23. You can solve this problem with ContentProvider. DPreference uses a ContentProvider wrappering sharepreference. It has a better performance than using sqlite implmented.
 https://github.com/DozenWang/DPreference

Answer (score 1):

Because MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is not currently supported, I haven't found any way to work with Shared Preferences between processes other than working around it.

I know people are sharing the libraries they wrote to address this, but I actually used a third-party library I found on [another thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14359) that implements SQLLite in lieu of the Shared Preferences:

https://github.com/hamsterready/dbpreferences

However, what was important to me that I haven't found addressed in other solutions was maintaining the automatic UI generation already built into Preference Fragment - better to be able to specify your elements in XML and call addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences) than have to build your UI from scratch.

So, to make this work, I subclassed each of the Preference elements I needed (in my case just Preference, SwitchPreference, and EditTextPreference), and overrode a few methods from the base classes to include saving to an instance of DatabaseSharedPreferences taken from the above library.

For example, below I subclass EditTextPreference and get the preference key from the base class. I then override the persist and getPersisted methods in Preference base class. I then override onSetInitialValue, setText, and getText in the EditText base class.

```
public class EditTextDBPreference extends EditTextPreference {
private DatabaseBasedSharedPreferences mDBPrefs;
private String mKey;
private String mText;

public EditTextDBPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public EditTextDBPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public EditTextDBPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public EditTextDBPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context)
{
    mDBPrefs = new DatabaseBasedSharedPreferences(context);
    mKey = super.getKey();
}

public DatabaseBasedSharedPreferences getSharedDBPreferences()
{
    if (mDBPrefs == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return mDBPrefs;
}

@Override
protected boolean persistBoolean(boolean value) {
    if (mKey != null)
        mDBPrefs.putBoolean(mKey,value);
    return super.persistBoolean(value);
}

@Override
protected boolean persistFloat(float value) {
    if (mKey != null)
        mDBPrefs.putFloat(mKey, value);
    return super.persistFloat(value);
}

@Override
protected boolean persistInt(int value) {
    if (mKey != null)
        mDBPrefs.putInt(mKey, value);
    return super.persistInt(value);
}

@Override
protected boolean persistLong(long value) {
    if (mKey != null)
        mDBPrefs.putLong(mKey, value);
    return super.persistLong(value);
}

@Override
protected boolean persistString(String value) {
    if (mKey != null)
        mDBPrefs.putString(mKey, value);
    return super.persistString(value);
}

@Override
protected boolean getPersistedBoolean(boolean defaultReturnValue) {
    if (mKey == null)
        return false;
    return mDBPrefs.getBoolean(mKey, defaultReturnValue);
}

@Override
protected float getPersistedFloat(float defaultReturnValue) {
    if (mKey == null)
        return -1f;
    return mDBPrefs.getFloat(mKey, defaultReturnValue);
}

@Override
protected int getPersistedInt(int defaultReturnValue) {
    if (mKey == null)
        return -1;
    return mDBPrefs.getInt(mKey, defaultReturnValue);
}

@Override
protected long getPersistedLong(long defaultReturnValue) {
    if (mKey == null)
        return (long)-1.0;
    return mDBPrefs.getLong(mKey, defaultReturnValue);
}

@Override
protected String getPersistedString(String defaultReturnValue) {
    if (mKey == null)
        return null;
    return mDBPrefs.getString(mKey, defaultReturnValue);
}

@Override
public void setKey(String key) {
    super.setKey(key);
    mKey = key;
}

@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
    setText(restoreValue ? getPersistedString(mText) : (String) defaultValue);
}

@Override
public void setText(String text) {
    final boolean wasBlocking = shouldDisableDependents();
    boolean textChanged = false;
    if (mText != null && !mText.equals(text))
        textChanged = true;
    mText = text;

    persistString(text);
    if (textChanged) {
        // NOTE: This is a an external class in my app that I use to send a broadcast to other processes that preference settings have changed
        BASettingsActivity.SendSettingsUpdate(getContext());
    }
    final boolean isBlocking = shouldDisableDependents();
    if (isBlocking != wasBlocking) {
        notifyDependencyChange(isBlocking);
    }
}

@Override
public String getText() {
    return mText;
}
```

Then you simply specify the new element in your preferences.xml file, and voila!
You now get the process interoperability of SQLLite and the UI auto-generation of PreferenceFragment!

```
<com.sampleproject.EditTextDBPreference
        android:key="@string/pref_key_build_number"
        android:title="@string/build_number"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:selectable="false"
        android:persistent="false"
        android:shouldDisableView="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but still a problem that many folks have tried to resolve with a `ContentProvider`, but that is a problematic approach, as it can cause ANRs, crashes, and general UI performance problems if read/write calls are not done on a background thread.

I don't mean this to be a plug, however, I wrote a library that implements the `SharedPreference` interface that is process-safe, but doesn't utilize `ContentProvider` (it uses `FileObserver` to sync data between processes). https://github.com/pablobaxter/Harmony

My hope is that this solves the issue many folks are having with trying to use `SharedPreferences` in multiple processes, and still keep their apps performant.