# SharedPreference in service not update

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using a `SharedPreference` in a service and it works correctly the first time I run the app. If I change the value in another activity, then I found out that the value in service hasn't changed (in activity the value is correct). If I restart the app, then it has the correct value. That's to say, the `SharedPreference` in my service can only work normally once before I restart app.

I can't figure out the problem,  code is like this:

in service

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
Logger.d(this, "" + sp.getInt(SPConst.KEY_AVOID_DISTURB, 0));
```

in activity

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt(SPConst.KEY_AVOID_DISTURB, 1);
editor.commit();
```

If both set and get are done in service or activity, it worked right, if set in activity, and get in service, then it's wrong.

Comment: I think you are using activity context use application context for shared preference and then try

Comment: @MathanG I have tried, it doesn't work

Comment: You are using different keys KEY_AVOID_DISTURB and KEY_AVOID_DISTURB_TIME_SEGMENT use same keys.

Comment: @MathanG in the program it is right, I typed wrong content here. I have tried to make SharePreference a sington when Application was created, but it still doesn't give right answer.

Comment: Ensure that your activity is called get after activity set the value. it can be called before setting value.

Comment: @MathanG set mode to `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find out the answer, maybe background service and activity are not in the same process, so set mode to `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`:

```
SharedPreferences sp = SnsService.this.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

Comment: Please read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129717/mode-multi-process-for-sharedpreferences-isnt-working

Comment: MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is deprecated. Is there any other way for solving this problem ?

Comment: @SajadNorouzi Yes, using MODE_MULTI_PROCESS to solve the problem of communication between processes is a bad idea, you can use binder, broadcast or contentprovider.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your data in service class ,just put your code in onStartCommand() method. and call again start-service . Passing an Intent that specifies the service and includes any data for the service to use. The service receives this Intent in the onStartCommand() method.