# sharedPreferences wont update if edited in another process

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, process

I have an unity activity, which launches in another process than my App:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".UnityActivity"
        android:process=":UnityKillsMe"/>
```

I save my `SharedPreferences` encrypted with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-store-user-settings-in-android-application) (just in case this affects my problem and I have no idea).

Now  if I want to edit a sharedPreference in `process=":UnityKillsMe"`, the edits are not beeing accessable in `mainProcess`, it just takes the old version of the `SharedPreferences`. Not until I kill the `mainProcess` and launch the app again. If I do not kill the `mainProcess`, and edit the `SharedPreferences`, while they have been edited in `process=":UnityKillsMe"`, the edits will be overwritten, and are lost.

How do I refresh `SharedPreferences` in the main process ?

Comment: another process?  unity is completely single-threaded.  you should not use or be involved in other processes at the Android level in any way whatsoever.  there is no conceivable reason you would need to do any such thing to make a simple video game.  Perhaps you should **state what you are trying to do?**

Comment: thanks @JoeBlow for helping. this question is more about java than unity, I launch my untiyactivity(my inapp videogame) from my Java application on android. But I fixed it with the answer below.

Comment: Dear Emanuel.  Fair enough, I get what you mean.  It is a huge PITA to treat unity projects as separate activities on Android.  I hope, it does not cause you too much trouble!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation of `SharedPreferences` in Android is  not process-safe.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

> Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple
>   processes. This will be added later.

The question is do you **really** need multiple processes in your application?

If you really do, i would suggest you to take a look at [Tray](https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray), or consider some other form of persistent storage, such as a database.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27987956/3363481) also.